# How to smooth frequency spectrum of time series?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, fft

I tried to reproduce Watson's spectrum plot from [these set of slides](https://assets.aeaweb.org/asset-server/files/8726.pdf) (PDF p. 30, p.29 of the slides), that came from [this data of housing building permits](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/PERMITNSA).

Watson achieves a very smooth spectrum curve in which it is very easy to tell the peak frequencies.
When I tried to run a FFT on the data, I get a really noisy spectrum curve and I wonder if there is an intermediate step that I am missing.

I ran the fourier analysis on python, using scipy package fftpack as follows:

```py
from scipy import fftpack

fs = 1 / 12 # monthly
N = data.shape[0]
spectrum = fftpack.fft(data.PERMITNSA.values)
freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(len(spectrum)) #* fs

plt.plot(freqs[:N//2], 20 * np.log10(np.abs(spectrum[:N//2])))
```

Could anyone help me with the missing link?

The original data is:

[image: original data]

Below is the Watson's spectrum curve, the one I tried to reproduce:

[image: target spectrum]

And these are my results:

[image: my results]

Comment: I'd assume he's used one of many [spectral density estimation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation) techniques. Maybe I missed it but did not see which one he used in that document you linked. Possibly a parametric one (such as an AR model) to estimate the autocorrelation coefficients, then use the ACGF to interpolate.

Comment: Notice that Watson's peaks are evenly spaced?  The spectral resolution in his plot is extremely low, and those peaks are sample positions, between which values have been interpolated.  There are only 7 frequencies in the graph. It looks like the method he used to produce this graph would show exactly the same peaks, with different amplitudes, no matter what the data was.

Answer (score 2):

The posted curve doesn't look realistic.  But there are many methods to get a smooth result with a similar amount of "curviness", using various kinds of resampling and/or plot interpolation.

One method I like is to chop the data into segments (windows, possibly overlapped) roughly 4X longer than the maximum number of "bumps" you want to see, maybe a bit longer.  Then window each segment before using a much longer (size of about the resolution of the final plot you want) zero-padded FFT.  Then average the results of the multiple FFTs of the multiple windowed segments.  This works because a zero-padded FFT is (almost) equivalent to a highest-quality Sinc interpolating low-pass filter.